# how to add submenu items in navigation with pyroCMS

Tags: navigation, pyrocms

I have pages that are children of other pages, and would like them to show up as menu items in a dropdown (something like superfish)

In pyroCMS 1.0.3 how do I add that ability?

I've found a tutorial http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/139227/P150/ but it references to files that don't exist so it must be for an older version of pyroCMS.

I'm stuck at step 6. adding a function to the helper.

Comment: The navigation helper has been removed. Instead you will want to work with system/pyrocms/navigation/plugin.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it without making some modifications. I would take a look at this pull request on github https://github.com/pyrocms/pyrocms/pull/62

Answer (score 0):

You can create it in the Control Panel, just **drag and drop** the nav link under the parent.

If in your theme you're using the menu tag this should be display automatically.

Try to see how to use it: http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/manual/plugins/navigation